# Using prepositions for "finance" and "fund"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage

I am writing a short content matter on behalf of my client. He runs an NGO and is planning for a crowdfunding campaign so that the NGO can provide free education to children from poor families.

Is it grammatically correct or wrong to use prepositions for "finance" and "fund" in the given sentences below?

The sentence: Families are struggling to finance *for/towards* the education of their children.

Or shall I only use "finance the education"?

Also, if I replace the word **finance** with **fund**, then also is it correct to use a preposition like for/towards?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What’s wrong with “to pay for”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using it 'finance' is a verb, financing the education is something the parents are doing and no preposition is needed as the education is the object of that verb.

However 'finance' can also be a noun and a preposition is normally needed then. The normal way to say it would be "The parents struggle to find *the* finance *for* their children's education".

The preposition 'towards' would normally be used with 'finance' as a noun when someone else was offering to pay part of the cost. For example "The charitable trust gives finance *towards* the education of children in need."

Comment: "Fund" is similar except that the noun in this context would be plural - "The parents struggle to find the *funds* for their children's education".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Peter Yes, I didn't address that part of the question, thanks for repairing my omission. I was going to say that 'towards' is used rarely if at all with 'funds' until I tried "The charitable trust gives funds _towards_ the cost of education of children in need." and realised that in that case it is perfectly normal. For me  _towards_ is used when the money provided does not meet the full cost of the need whereas _for_ is used both in that case and in the one where the full cost is met.